# MoPub - Deciding how to display tablet or phone advert?

Tags: android, ads, mopub

Maybe I'm just being a complete noob but I signed up to MoPub and learnt how to put an advert into my android app, I managed that just fine. Before with AdMob I could define a "SMART_BANNER" in the XML. This would solve the whole tablet/phone issue. I wouldn't have to worry about making sure the banner advert fits the screen correctly because AdMob sort that all out.

With MoPub you have a different Ad unit ID for each advert, so I have two ID's, one for phones and one for tablets. How do I implement this in my code? I mean I can only input one Id... can't I?

```
mAdView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.Advert);
  mAdView.setAdUnitId("ONE AD UNIT ID HERE");
  mAdView.loadAd();
```

Does anyone know what I should do? If a user opens my app on a phone or tablet they should both get banner ads that fit correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, probably something I should have known already. A simple conditional statement will solve this.

Comment: How did you manage that? I mean, which condition did you use?

Comment: First use DisplayMetrics to get the width of the device, then a simply if statement that says if width is bigger then say 720 run advert with tablet ad unit ID, else run the phone one.

Comment: Thanks, i've already managed how to display ads, literally one minute after i asked this question. That is one thing mopub should do in the future, it's stupid to double every position in app (i have six of them, not one that is always visible).

Comment: I use AdMob mediation with MoPub added to my mediation networks in the AdMob interface. How can I do to have AdMob choosing between tablet or phone ad units ?